# Lines and spaces everywhere disappeared

Tags: menu, file-manager

I wanted to use WebDav so installed Nautilus on my Linux Mint, but after that suddenly lines and spaces have disappeared all over the systems.

Find below the screenshots for the same,

[image]

I tried changing the file manager, with no help.

Comment: Have you tried removing Nautilus and any of the packages it also added?

Comment: yes i removed all the Nautilius and its dependent packages, using the following commands,
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nautilus
sudo apt-get remove nautilus

Comment: In hindsight it's a shame that wasn't `purge` rather than `remove`. I wonder what configuration files it's left in place :-(

Comment: Should I try with purge then?

Comment: Reinstall the package and then start too remove it but with `purge`. When you can see the list of packages that are going to be removed, stop the process and list them all explicitly on the `purge` line. This way all the dependencies will get purged as well as Nautilus itself

Comment: I tried it, its not working :(

Comment: Maybe `nautilus` has changed settings in `~/.config`. In order to test this, please create a new user, then log out and log in again, as that user. If it works, then as step 2 move your `~/.config` to a backup location (ideally when not logged in graphically, e.g. `mv -i ~myusername/.config ~myusername/.config.broken` when logged in as root), then log in again normally and let us know.

Comment: I added new user and logged in as the new user, it is the same, nothing has changed :(

Comment: OK, we are getting closer - so system settings have been changed, not user settings. The next step would be to modify system-wide settings for fonts and rendering. As a workaround and test, may I ask you to install xfce/xfce4 as an additional window manager (simply select "xfce4" meta-package in synaptic), then log out and select xfce upon login - then let us know whether rendering is better.

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes in xfce4 it is coming correct all menu options are having expected things. what do I need to do further.